# DatePickerで指定した時間に通知

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift3

リマインダーアプリ（オフライン）を作っていてDatePickerを使って指定した時間にUser Notificationsを使用して通知を出したいのですが、どのように書けば良いのか分かりません。
DatePickerの書き方とUser Notificationsの書き方を調べているのですが、解決に至っていません。ご教授お願いします。

追記
内容不足で申し訳ありません。
詳しくは DatePickerで日時指定した時間を取得し、、Notificationsで読み込ませて、ローカル通知を送ると言うとこまで分かったのですが、現在はDatePickerの普通の使い方とNotificationasで○秒後に発火と言うのはコードが分かるのですが、
DatePickerで日時指定をした時間にNotificationsを使ってローカル通知を送るというとこのコードが分かりません。
Googleで検索などをしたのですが、ヒットしないもので、、、

ご教授お願いします。

環境は
Swift3　Xcode8.3.3です

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/79844

Comment: おそらく困っていることが複数あるかと思います。DataPickerで日時を選択する、User Notificationsで通知を表示する。それぞれ何がどこまで出来て、何が出来なくて困っているかを詳細に追記してもらえませんか？

Comment: 情報不足で申し訳ありません。詳細な情報を追加しました。宜しくお願い致します。