# DatePickerで指定した日時に通知

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift4

DatePickerで指定した月、日、時間にローカル通知(UserNotifications)で通知をしたいのですが、どのように実装すれば良いのでしょうか？

ちなみにUNTimeInterValNotificationTrigger(timeInterVal: 30)など特定の秒数で通知する事は分かったのですが、DatePickerで指定した日時を組み込み通知するのが分かりません。
ご教授頂けると幸いです。宜しくお願いします。

Swift4

Comment: まずは[Appleの公式ドキュメント](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html)にざっくりと目を通されてはいかがでしょうか。また、自分ではここまでは出来る、と言うのをコードの形で示されると、あなたがより利用しやすい形の回答が得やすくなるでしょう。今のご質問内容だとAppleのドキュメントにあるような(正直わかりやすいには程遠い…)ごくごく一般的な解説と一般的なコード例しか示せそうにありません。

Comment: 15ヶ月ほど前に同じような質問をなされているようです（Swiftのバージョンは4になりましたが）https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/35462/datepicker%E3%81%A7%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E6%99%82%E9%96%93%E3%81%AB%E9%80%9A%E7%9F%A5

Comment: Appleの公式ドキュメントを見たのですが、実装方法が分かりませんでした。DatePickerの値をラベルに表示することまでは出来ました              @IBAction func datePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        
        formatter.dateFormat = "yy/mm/dd HH:mm"
    }

Comment: ご返信が遅くなり申し訳ありませんでした。宜しくお願いします。